# Replace string in a vector of structs C++

Tags: c++, string, vector, struct, replace

I'm new to C++ and I got stuck. 
I have a problem replacing `|` with `,`. I have no problem finding `|`, but replace function doesn't seem to work. What am I doing incorrectly? Any help appreciated.

Header File:

```
struct Document

{
    string text;
    int NumLines;
};

struct Find {
    const string text;
    Find(const string& text) : text(text) {}
    bool operator()(const Document& j) const { 
        return j.text == text; 
    }
};
class DataRecord
{
    private: 
    vector <Document> field;

    public:
        void Replace();
}
```

cpp. file for this function

```
void DataRecord::Replace ()
{
    vector<Document>::iterator it = replace(field.begin(),field.end(),Find("|"),"," );
}
```

Comment: What does doesn't seem to work mean? A compile error or goes wrong at runtime? Are you trying to use `std::replace` in the `algorithm` header?

Comment: I have <algorithm> header. I'm getting compiler error C2782: 'void std::replace(_FwdIt,_FwdIt,const _Ty &,const _Ty &)' : template parameter '_Ty' is ambiguous.

Comment: You will get better answers in future if you say if "doesn't work" means at compile time(and post the error), link time (and post the error) or at runtime (and again post any errors you see)

Answer (score 1):

What you are attempting isn't clear, but if all you want to do is replace all the `"|"` for `","` in every `Document` in `field`, the simplest approach might be a loop:

```
for (auto& f : field) :
  std::replace(f.text.begin(), f.text.end(), '|', ',');
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that is what I'm attempting to do. I tried your approach, it doesn't work in my code.

Comment: @KatieP - what does "doesn't work" mean? More compile errors? Does your compiler support the C++11 range based for loop?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to replace documents in the sequence `fields` with a string literal. This does not work.

`std::replace` semantics:

```
std::replace(It begin, It end, Predicate P, Value v)
```

where:

- `*begin` (and any element in the sequence [begin, end)) yields a value of type `Value`.
- Predicate has the semantics `P(const Value&) -> bool`.
- `v` in the value that should be set instead of the elements matching the predicate.

In your case, the fourth argument (`v`) should be of type `Document`, not a string literal.

You should create a document instance that specifies what should replace the Document instances matching the predicate (because you cannot replace them with string instances or string literals).

**Edit**: Alternately, you could add an implicit Document constructor that creates an instance from a string, but creating implicit constructors like that is usually a bad idea.

Comment: I understand and it works for me with the regular strings or vectors of strings. However, I have a trouble of accessing one element of the struct Document (string text). I tried putting searched values in the  struct, but then it distorts my other functions.